# Passed arguments in shell script as well as get data from CSV file

Tags: shell, csv

Here CSV file content below data

CSVfile: test.csv
Records:
Name, ID, Department1, Department2, Department3, Product
Rohan,501,Production,Sales,IT,Telephones
Rahul,502,IT,Marketing,Sales,Mobiles
Mayank,503,Sales,Salessupport,Customerinquiry,Telecommunication

Script: test.sh -> here I need to find details of first column and forth column and store that values into the variable and when I run the file need to take 2 arguments

So suppose If I select name and department2 it need to print
Run: .test/sh name department3

**Output:**
Rohan IT
Rahul Sales
Mayank CustomerInquiry

```
 #!/bin/bash
    
    IFS=","
    args="$@"
    while read name department2
    do
           echo "First argument is: ${args[$name]}"
           echo "Second argument is: ${args[$department2]}"
    
    done < test.csv
```

Comment: Awk is ideal for scenarios such as these

Comment: Thank you. Awk command is working but only print data from file without user input.

Comment: You can pass variables into awk with -v. These can be set to the parameters passed into your script.